# Boolean variable within a function not changing the value of said variable within the global scope

Tags: javascript, function, boolean-logic

I'm trying to create a basic RPG game for a class that I'm in, and currently running into an issue with a boolean Variable. I have an on click function set to run a certain list of commands, and then change my Boolean var within the global scope to true. This should then trigger an if else that  if (Var === true) a new set of commands should fire. However I must be missing something because unless I set the if statement within the scope of that first function my console.log doesn't fire.

```
var CharhasbeenSelelcted = false;


//first on click function for getting player boxes aligned properly
$(".Pcontainer").on("click", function(){

if(CharhasbeenSelelcted === false){
//setting the attribute of whatever you've clicked so the append command 
given no longer applies to it
$(this).attr( "class", "Chosenplayer")

$('.Pcontainer').attr( "class", "Enemyplayer")

//append the newly assigned class to its own area of the screen
$("#MainCharcterArea").append( $(".Chosenplayer") );

//append all other boxes to enemy area
$('#EnemyContain').append( $('.Enemyplayer') );

} else {
} 

CharhasbeenSelelcted = true;

});

//-----------------------scope issue I can't quite figure out 
if(CharhasbeenSelelcted === true) {

        console.log("attack button working");

    };
```

No error messages to be seen thus far, which is actually more frustrating. lol

Comment: The variable changes when `.Pcontainer` is clicked. That doesn't mean your `if` statement gets re-evaluated. That is done immediately after *defining* the onclick handler, so by the time the user gets around to clicking it, that code has already been executed.

Comment: you need to move your if logic inside the event handler.You need to re evaluate every time a user clicks